# An issue when uploading CSV file using Selenide on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testing, automated-tests, selenide

Im trying to upload CSV file from local storage.

**Driver initialization:**

```
private static RemoteWebDriver createRemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities caps) throws MalformedURLException {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(getBrowserstackURL(), caps);
        driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        return driver;
    }
```

**Upload method:**

```
public void uploadFileUniversal(String fileName, SelenideElement uploadAreaElement) {
        uploadAreaElement.shouldBe(Condition.enabled, DefaultDuration.DEFAULT);
        LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
        File localFile = detector.getLocalFile("src/test/resources/" + fileName);
        uploadAreaElement.sendKeys(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

**Page:**

```
<span class="btn btn-default upload-csv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
    <span class="upload-btn-text">Import CSV</span>
    <input id="select-upload-csv" type="file" name="select-upload-assets" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
</span>
```

**CSV:**

```
Slide,Time
1,00:10
2,00:15
3,00:20
```

As result, I have gotten a validation message from FE. An issue appears only using Jenkins, locally it works like a charm.

Comment: Were you tried printing the `localFile.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: @NandanA yes. Path looks like `/home/jenkins/workspace/run_repository/src/test/resources/test-data/csv/file_name.csv`

Comment: Can you try by using absolute path? like `System.getProperty("user.dir")+"src/test/resources/" + fileName`

Comment: @NandanA, It returns the same path

Comment: I think the issue is in the `SelenideElement uploadAreaElement`, if you are selecting the drop dev the `uploadAreaElement.sendKeys(localFile.getAbsolutePath());` will not work
Instead you should select the file input, example: `$("#select-upload-csv")`.